# if condition not working

Tags: sql

I want to show a message if record is not in the table.

I wrote this small piece of code, but it's giving me an error.

```
create procedure abc(@id varchar(25))
as
   declare @msg1 as varchar(55)
begin
   select id,fname,lname from student where id=@id
   --up to this is working correctly
   --for showing msg i write down this lince of code
   if id=@id
      select @msg=“correct record“
   else
      select @msg=“record not found“
   end
end
```

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Comment: Also maybe figure out what you want, your code makes no sense. In the absence of an explanation in words we're left to guess.

Comment: You need to set the value of the selected ID to something, anything.  The IF will not be able to resolve "id" in your code above.

Comment: You declared msg1, but then used msg (without the 1).

Answer (score 3):

Add an EXISTS check instead of selecting the records

```
IF EXISTS ( select 1 from student where id=@id)
BEGIN
   SET @msg = 'correct record'
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
   SET @msg = 'incorrect record'
END
```

Are you trying to return the value of @msg? If yes, add `SELECT @msg` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes not double.  And check for any results with @@rowcount

```
create procedure abc(@id varchar(25))
as
begin
   select id,fname,lname from student where id=@id

 if @@rowcount > 0
      select 'correct record' as msg
   else
      select 'record not found' as msg
   end
end
```